# ImportError: No module named optparse in jython

Tags: python, jython

getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\projects\myproject\convert.py", line 139, in <module>
    import optparse
ImportError: No module named optparse.
```

when executing it using jython. Same module works fine when i execute it through python.

I am usinng window7 operating system. The same modle works fine on windows XP machine with both python and Jython.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're using Jython 2.2, which, [according to the FAQ](http://www.jython.org/archive/22/userfaq.html):

> Jython 2.2 does not implement any features added to CPython in version 2.3 or later.

Where `optparse` [was added in Python 2.3](http://www.jython.org/docs/library/optparse.html).

The newest version of Jython is 2.5.1, so you'll probably want to go ahead and [download it](http://www.jython.org/downloads.html).

Comment: Strange, I'm running Jython 2.5.2 and have the same issue